difference in meaning between [of the month] and [of this month]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) We will complete our project at the end of the month.
(1b) We will complete our project at the end of this month.
(2a) My contract ends on the last day of the month.
(2b) My contract ends on the last day of this month.
In these sentences, what is the difference in meaning between "this month" and "the month"? Thanks.

There's little difference, although "the month" can also be used if some other month has been set as the context.

There is a recurring joke about a guy who promises his project will be finished "at the end of the month". When asked a month later why it isn't finished he says "I didn't say which month".

"The" month does not specify which month. It can be assumed to be the current month, but could be used otherwise, e.g., "My contract ends on the last day of the month school closes." A better example:
Your rent is due on the last day of the month.

This implies each and every month. In that case, one could not use "this".
